# Como tratar a espera pelo carregamento de algum dado no Playwright?

Tags: javascript, testes-automatizados, e2e

Estou criando testes end-to-end automatizados para uma aplicação web com o Playwright e estou tendo uma dúvida quanto a qual seria a melhor maneira de criar um tempo de espera quando há o carregamento da aplicação ou algum serviço

Nos testes, eu uso muito (não sempre, claro) os [screenshots](https://playwright.dev/docs/screenshots) para testar o resultado das interações, o problema é que preciso ter certeza que os estilos, imagens e fontes já tenham carregado e as animações/ transições terminaram para que a comparação não falhe

Pensei em 3 formas de definir esse intervalo de carregamento, porém todos são falhos e causam falsos negativos eventualmente:

- [`waitForTimeout`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout)

Falha se houver alguma instabilidade na rede ou no servidor, que cause um atraso maior no carregamento, além de aumentar o tempo ocioso dos testes (não é crítico os testes demorarem, mas é preferível que sejam rápidos)

- [`waitForSelector`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector)

Em alguns casos, a resposta chega, o elemento é renderizado, porém, devido a alguma transição/animação, a comparação dos screenshots falha

- [`waitForResponse`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response)

É bom no setup e uso muito, já que não faço testes, quando eu apenas preciso ter certeza que a resposta chegou para salvar os Cookies, LocalStorage e SessionStorage necessários. Em outros casos tende a falhar, já que, ter a resposta, não implica necessariamente que tudo esteja renderizado e pronto

Já pensei em usar outras formas de comparação, como o [`locator.innerHTML`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-inner-html), porém achei melhor os screenshots por testarem também se os estilos estão sendo aplicados corretamente e se não quebraram (após alterações), também é vantajoso por não sofrer impacto por alterações de estrutura (alterações nas tags, por exemplo) ou nomenclatura (nome das classes CSS, por exemplo), desde que o resultado final continue o mesmo ─ útil se eu fizer alguma alteração num componente que é utilizado por muitos outros, como os botões ou campos de texto, que só impactaria o resultado final em algum caso específico relacionado a alteração, como adicionar um novo estado que é utilizado para estilizar as vezes

Atualmente os testes consultam o backend hospedado, sei que poderia interceptar as requisições e mockear os resultados, eliminando o problema, porém desejo que os testes e2e realmente sejam de ponta a ponta, testando tudo, do cliente até o servidor da aplicação, de arquivos e do banco de dados

Alguém conhece alguma outra solução que resolva esses problemas?

Comment: Use o waitForResponse para o que ele foi feito, para esperar o carregamento inicial, o waitForSelector como você disse funciona, mas pode ter atraso devido a delays, mas é por isso mesmo que você deve combinar o waitForSelector com algo extra direto na interface do documento, se a ideia é checar transições CSS ou animações CSS, você pode usar o método nativo [`Element.getAnimations()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations) nesse caso após usar o `waitForSelector` você pode checar o estado de cada animação de um elemento.

Comment: Observação, você também pode pegar as propriedades CSS em "tempo de execução" usando [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), isso entendendo que você conhece o site ao qual vai aplicar os testes, claro que não tem como ser 100% assertivo e ao mesmo tempo criar algo que funcione globalmente (para qualquer website), tem que conhecer de fato o comportamento do site e aplicar a lógica, que pode ser usando getComputedStyle.